# Displaying images in new line using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display 2 images in a line below a line of text, but they show up in the same line. I tried using the "clear: both" property and "display: block" property in the CSS style for the images. What am I missing?

I included a screenshot of what it looks like as well as the relevant section of the HTML code and the complete CSS stylesheet. The "media" class is what I am using for the images. They are showing on the same line as the

section under the "Contacts" div.

[screenshot of website here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB49q.png)

```css
body {
  background-color: #63a4ff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #63a4ff 0%, #83eaf1 74%);
}

.fadeline {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 25px 20%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 1px;
}

.fadeline.white {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

.fadeline.black {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.row {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0% 15% 0% 15%;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  color: #586E95;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 40%;
}

#about {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.example {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10%;
  outline: none;
  width: 20%;
}

a,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

img {
  max-height: 90%;
  max-width: 90%;
}

.media {
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact" class="row text-center">
  <h1 class="header">Contact</h1>
  <div class="fadeline black"></div>

  <p> Want to connect? Reach out with Facebook or LinkedIn.</p>

  <div class='media'>
    <a href='https://www.facebook.com/siddharth.gampa/'><img src='https://facebookbrand.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/f_logo_RGB-Hex-Blue_512.png?w=512&h=512'></a>
  </div>
  <div class='media'>
    <a href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/siddharth-gampa/'><img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/174/174857.svg'></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place both images in one `div` with the class `.media` then set that div to `display: flex` that should work.

Check out the example code below by clicking the `Run code snippet`

```css
body {
  background-color: #63a4ff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #63a4ff 0%, #83eaf1 74%);
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 15%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  color: #586E95;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
}

.fadeline {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 25px 20%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 1px;
}

.fadeline.white {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

.fadeline.black {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.media {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

a img {
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact" class="row text-center">

  <h1 class="heading">Contact</h1>
  <div class="fadeline black"></div>

  <p> Want to connect? Reach out with Facebook or LinkedIn.</p>

  <div class='media'>
    <a href='https://www.facebook.com/siddharth.gampa/'>
      <img src='https://facebookbrand.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/f_logo_RGB-Hex-Blue_512.png?w=512&h=512'>
    </a>
    <a href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/siddharth-gampa/'>
      <img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/174/174857.svg'>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they're not below the text because they're in the same div with the row class.
Put them in a div below the row and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to both images. For example
Class="img-1"
And
Class="img-2"
Make their position relative then push one of the images to the right. It may take some fiddling to get the locations correct